French movie with two teen boys who accidentally murder a man deal with guilt differently
I saw this movie years ago and I'd like to find it again, since I don't remember the name of it. I remember the plot thorough so if it helps.
I guess the boys' names were Jacques and Yves. They get into a bar underage, get out intoxicated, it's winter, break into a house, trash it, neighbor comes to see what is going on. The boys panic and push him (the neighbor, a middle-aged man) out of the way. He slips on ice and his skull breaks.
The smaller of the boys, who I'll call Jacques, recognizes him as his old boy scouts leader and is horrified. They flee and discuss about it. Yves is angry and says he won't spend the best years of his life in jail. Jacques is gradually eaten by guilt but doesn't tell anybody. His single-mother starts to notice him getting depressed. 
Jacques goes to see the man's widow as well and she cries how they never got children and how his late husband loved the scout kids as his own. Jacques is desperate and decides to kill himself, locks the bathroom door and slits his wrists open in a tub. His mother comes home worried and breaks through the door and the most intense scene happens where Jacques sits in his own blood, holds his wrist to stop bleeding and looks up to his mother; "I don't want to die". 
In the next scene, when cops come to arrest Yves from his school, (studying to be a firefighter if I remember right) and he knows why and surrenders without resisting. Yves and Jacques meet at the hospital and reconcile after falling out. They are put through trial. Somewhat over a half a year has gone, since at the end of the movie it's summer. Movie was shown in an annual European movies week for students in Finland 2011.
I cried my eyes out five years ago when watching this and haven't found it since even though I've looked through french movie lists. I'm sure the movie was filmed in the 2000's.

Sounds like La vérité (2011)

Winter in a small town in Quebec. Gabriel, a teenager, lives with his mother who is a police officer. His best friend Yves is the star of the high school's football team and lives with his father. One evening, after a party, they break into a house and begin to vandalize everything. Caught in the act by a neighbor, they decide to flee, but by doing so, they cause the accidental death of the man who slips on an ice patch. Because the police have no suspect, Yves believes they can get away with it and just keep living their lives. Gabriel, on the other hand, has difficulty dealing with his remorse, especially when his friend decides to go live with his mother and study in another city.

